# rotate image without cropping it, with skimage

Tags: python, image, image-processing

I'm using skimage to rotate, zoom and translate an image. The returned image uses the original image shape, thus cropping the original image. How can I return an image that contains the entire original image?

```
from skimage import data
from skimage import transform as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

image = data.chelsea()

tform = tf.SimilarityTransform(scale=1, rotation=math.pi / 4,
                               translation=(image.shape[0] / 2, -100))    

rotated = tf.warp(image, tform)

plt.imshow(rotated)
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure if this would solve your question, but you could just calculate a scale parameter based on the bounding rectangle and scale the image down too.

Comment: Does it really have to be done with skimage? This functionality is present too in scipy, without cropping.

Comment: Any tool would do. Do you have an example of code of how you'd do it in scipy?

Comment: just use `transform.rotate(img, angle, resize=True)` if you don't need to do multiple transformations at once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a library other than [scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org/) is allowed to be used (as you mention in your comment), then scipy has just [the tool](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.interpolation.rotate.html) for this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.ndimage.interpolation import rotate
import scipy.misc
lena = scipy.misc.lena()
rotated_lena = rotate(lena, 30, reshape=True)
f, (ax0,ax1) = plt.subplots(1,2)
ax0.imshow(lena, cmap='gray')
ax1.imshow(rotated_lena, cmap='gray')
plt.show()  # shows a normal version of Lena and a version that is rotated by 30° CCW, uncropped
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import skimage

#Set the argument **resize = True** to get the uncropped 
skimage.transform.rotate(image,angle=45,resize=False, mode='constant')
```